# Setting an analytics custom metric server side

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm using the GTM data layer to populate data through the enhanced ecommerce interface of Analytics.  The goal is to provide detailed cost data so I can build a dashboard that shows profitability for my business.  It's working great on a transaction basis and I am uploading shipping costs, product costs, discounts, and a host of other transaction data.  However, my business also has fixed overhead costs.  I want to upload that to analytics once per day so I can see the true profitability on a day by day basis.  This requires it to be a server-side request from my PHP server.  I am unfamiliar with how to set a custom metric from the server side.  Does anyone know how I can send this once-per-day data to analytics from the server side?  Would I send it as a pageview event?  The variable name would be "fixed overhead".  I'm not really sure where to start.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending data server-side to Google Analytics is entirely possible (and admittedly it is pretty daunting if you've not done it before).

The two best resources to use are the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#event) and the [Google Analytics Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/). Use the [parameter guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cm_) to prep the custom metric data specifically.

[Here is my actual snippet](https://github.com/chrisblakley/Nebula/blob/master/functions/nebula_utilities.php) that I use for all of my PHP projects (first ~150 lines or so). I'm certain there are better ways to do it, but at the very least it might help you figure out some of the complexities.

It's a lot of info to soak in, but I hope that gets you headed in the right direction!

Comment: The last link is broken. I guess it is now here: https://github.com/chrisblakley/Nebula/blob/master/libs/Utilities/Utilities.php

Comment: Sorry about that. The measurement protocol stuff has actually been moved to here: https://github.com/chrisblakley/Nebula/blob/master/libs/Utilities/Analytics.php